# IE9 Rendering issue with Bootstrap buttons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-9

IE9 seems to make disabled buttons really f0rking uggly using Twitter Bootstrap. The button text becomes blurry and I cannot find any way to remove this blur or even reset to the default IE9 button look..

[image: IE9 bootstrap disabled button text rendering problem]

The best solution would be if someone could solve this font/blur rendering problem. If this is not possible I would like to have the default IE9 button look and feel since this is at least readable.

**I'm not looking to download any patch or just fix this in just my own browser!**

I've attempted to reset the IE9 button look but for some reason this seems impossible. The color of the text becomes grey with what looks like an ugly old IE filter on it.

[image: IE9 bootstrap button reset not working]

I've included a LT IE10 stylesheet in the end of `<head>`

```
<!--[if lt IE 10]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie9.css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
```

with the following css:

```
.btn.disabled,
.btn[disabled] {
    background: 0;
    background-color: #a9a2a1;
    opacity: 1;
    filter: none !important;
    text-shadow: none !important;
    -ms-color: #000000 !important;
    color: #000000 !important;
    zoom: 1;    
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: black !important;
}
```

still the text is grey and the button looks like the gray one above...

#### My solution:

Thanks to Emily's answer I made a hack:

```
#sok.btn.disabled,
#sok.btn[disabled] {
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 0;
    background-image: url('image.jpg');
    width: 48px;
}
```

All other css rules can be left alone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bootstrap guys do mention this on their github page, and they don't currently have a way of fixing it. It's an issue with IE9 only as it overrides their code, and anyone else's. There isn't currently a way of fixing this, although I suppose you could experiment with creating a disabled button image, and using a higher z-index to put it over the top of the nasty-looking button, although that is probably a fair amount of hassle... Hope that helps.

Comment: I ended up doing font-size: 0; and a bg-image :/

Comment: Now I've changed the font I regret only doing an image.. damn ie crap

Answer (score 2):

you will need to add following style in case of IE 9,

in your HTML :

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
 <link href="/bootstrap/i9_btn_fix.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
<![endif]-->
```

i9_btn_fix.css :

```
.btn.disabled:before,
.btn.disabled:after{
     cursor: default;
     background-image: none;
     opacity: 0.65;
     filter: alpha(opacity=65);
     -moz-box-shadow: none;
     box-shadow: none;
   }
```

Comment: Not super helpful, I know, but this doesn't work at all for me. The only attributes I've found that affect IE9 text rendering here are font-size and text-decoration, neither of which fix this. Another appropach is to not actually disable the button, instead apply a class to make it look how you want, and handle the click in javascript, but that's not good from an accessibility POV. No good options.